# Project Oxford & Speech Recognition - "This assembly was compiled for a different processor"

Tags: azure-functions

I have added the following project.json file to my Azure function.

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition-x86": "1.0.0.1"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

I'm using a simple Http trigger and have the following code in the function:

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognition;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log) {
log.Info($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var dataClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.CreateDataClient(
                    SpeechRecognitionMode.LongDictation,
                    "en-US",
                    "my sub key");

        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return resp;
}
```

At this point, I am just trying to create an instance of the DataClient.  The function compiles fine, but when it is executed, throws this error.

*Functions.ProcessReportAudio. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly 'SpeechClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. This assembly was compiled for a different processor.*

I have tried both the x86 and x64 version of the nuget package and get the same error.

Ultimately, I will be processing speech wav files that have been uploaded to Azure Storage to get dictation, but kind of dead in the water right now.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff, 
I'm assuming you started with x64 (since the default Function App configuration is x86).

After changing from one architecture to the other, have you restarted your Function App?

Can you give that a try as an initial binding failure would potentially be cached, and since the assemblies have the same name, that would prevent the runtime from attempting to load the reference after your change.